# How to install xubuntu 23.10 in non-UEFI machine

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, bios

I´m trying to install xubuntu-23.10-minimal on my HP Compaq 8000 Elite USDT.

According to this:
https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/does-my-hp-elite-8000-sff-pc-support-UEFI/td-p/6531757

This machine doesn´t support boot in UEFI mode.

At some point during installation, the installer warns about creating UEFI partition or else continue at my own risk.

Is it safe to dismiss this warning?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, you can install on an older pre-uEFI machine with all releases of Ubuntu (*and flavors like Xubuntu*) up to the current Ubuntu 23.10. The system will boot.

The message that worries you is **only a warning** that it may not boot if your machine has uEFI, but it has been temporarily disabled (via uEFI/BIOS setting). As your machine has no such setting that can be *reversed*, your system will always boot.

I perform QA-testing using a number of devices, including a

`hp dc7700 (c2d-e6320, 5gb, nvidia quadro nvs 290)`

which predates uEFI by a number of years; and I get the warning that an ESP (*EFI System Partition*) isn't being created (some installer/ISOs will create one anyway; others do not (eg. Lubuntu's `calamares` does not create an ESP unless required to boot)).

All releases of Xubuntu up to 23.10 have booted on that pre-uEFI machine I use for install testing.